# Project Tango Unity tutorials fail

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm trying to walk through these two Project Tango Unity tutorials:
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-depth-perception
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-motion-tracking

In each of them I get stopped in my tracks by what appears to be a lack of a Unity Plugin (I assume from the Tango SDK .unitypackage).  I followed the instructions to import the downloaded Tango SDK .unitypackage but for some reason don't have to option to add a PointCloud component (for the depth tutorial) or a Sample Controller (for the motion tracking tutorial).

I've tried following the tutorial with both Unity 4.6 (as it seems the tutorials were based off of) and the latest version of Unity 5 on a Mac.

Can anyone offer some guidance on what I am overlooking or doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, Unity tutorials have been deprecated as there was major change in Project Tango Unity SDK last release. For now you can look at these [sample projects](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that there were no links to these tutorials.  I have tried loading the sample projects into Unity but result in what appears to be a blank project.  Any advice / links on how to load these samples into Unity?

Comment: Just import like how you would import any Unity Project.