# Tango Unity SDK tutorial example not working: Failed to connect to Tango Service

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm having troubles using the [motion tracking tutorial example for Unity](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-prefab-motion-tracking). When starting the app I get a toast message "**Failed to connect to Tango Service.**". I can see the scene, the camera seems to be working in the background (it's complaining if I cover it or am too close to objects), but there's no video overlay or movement in my scene. By looking a little into it: the return value of a function TangoService_connect is -1, corresponding to TANGO_ERROR. According to the Tango documentation: **"Returns TANGO_ERROR on failure, or if the camera could not be opened which could be due to cameras being opened by other applications or could be caused by a system error which may require a reboot."**. Reboot doesn't help and there seems to be no problem with the camera for any other app but this one. I tried looking into logcat output, but am not sure what exactly to look for and can't find any useful information.

I'm using **Tango Core version 1.42** and **Unity 5.3.1f1**. I'm of course on a Project Tango tablet and its system is up to date.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107426/google-tango-unity-examples-not-working) someone seems to have had the same problem, but no solution was found. I tried unchecking "Auto-connect to service" and doing the connection from a script like [here](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-user-permissions), same result. I'm not sure whether any other Tango Manager settings do the trick, I tried different combinations and of course the default ones.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498234/project-tango-unity-tutorials-fail) someone wrote the Unity tutorials had been deprecated, but it's from April while the tutorial website was last changed in June.

I'd be thankful for any ideas.

PS: I had the same problem with Tango Core 1.43. With factory version 1.37 it said "Incompatible version. Update to the latest Tango Core.".

Comment: Maybe that sample is not up to date. Try the sample projects from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was already the solution... I couldn't imagine the official website tutorial being outdated for such a long time. My bad. :/

Comment: Anytime and happy coding